# Count lines wider than 80 columns, taking tabs correctly into account

Tags: grep

To count lines wider than 80 columns I am, currently, using this command:

```
$ git grep -h -c -v '^.\{,80\}$' **/*.{c,h,p{l,y}} \
    |awk 'BEGIN { i=0 } { i+=$1 } END { printf ("%d\n", i) }'
44984
```

Unfortunately, the repo uses tabs for indenting so the `grep` pattern
is inaccurate. Is there anyway to have the `regex` treat tabs at the
standard width of 8 chars like how `wc -L` does?

For the purpose of this question, we may assume the contributors were disciplined enough to indent consistently, or that they have `git commit` hooks in lieu of discipline.

For reasons  related to performance, I’d prefer a solution that works inside
`git-grep(1)` or maybe another `grep` tool, *without preprocessing files*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we can assume per your comment that *tab* characters will appear only at the beginning of lines, then we can count alternatives to a minimum of 80 characters.

- No tabs, at least 81 characters
- One tab, at least 73 characters
- Two tabs, at least 65 characeters
- Etc.

The resulting mess is as follows, with your `awk` statement summing the individual line counts to provide a grand total

```
git grep -hcP '^(.{81,}|\t.{73,}|\t{2}.{65,}|\t{3}.{57,}|\t{4}.{49,}|\t{5}.{41,}|\t{6}.{33,}|\t{7}.{25,}|\t{8}.{17,}|\t{9}.{9,}|\t{10}.)' **/*.{c,h,p{l,y}} |
    awk '{ i+=$1 } END { printf ("%d\n", i) }'
```

Comment: Note that `git grep -P` (at least with my 2.18.0 version on Debian here) doesn't work with multi-byte characters. For instance, it considers that `©` (common in source files) is 2 characters instead of one when encoded in UTF-8. It's OK with `-E`. You can work around it in UTF-8 locales by writing `git grep -hcP '(*UTF8)...'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas if I change to `-E` then `\t` isn't recognised. The quick fix for that, I suppose, is to use an Ansi C -quoted string `$'...'` instead a single-quoted one `'...'`.

Answer (score 12):

Preprocess the files by piping them through `expand`.  The `expand` utility will expand tabs appropriately (using the standard tab stops at every 8th character).

```
find . -type f \( -name '*.[ch]' -o -name '*.p[ly]' \) -exec expand {} + |
awk 'length > 80 { n++ } END { print n }'
```

Answer (score 10):

GNU `wc -L` doesn't treat TABs as 8 characters, it treats TABs as they would be displayed in a terminal with TAB stops every 8 columns so would have a "width" ranging from 1 to 8 characters depending on where they're found on the line. `wc -L` also considers the display width of other characters (whether they're 0, 1 or 2 columns wide) and also processes `\f` and `\r` "correctly".

```
$ printf 'abcde\t\n' | wc -L
8
```

Here, you could use `expand` (which by default also assumes tab stops every 8 columns though you can change it with options) to expand those TABs to spaces:

```
git grep -h '' ./**/*.{c,h,p{l,y}} | expand | tr '\f\r' '\n\n' | grep -cE '.{81}'
```

(converting the CRs (which when sent to a terminal move the cursor back to the beginning of the line) and FFs (which some display devices understand as a page-break) to LF to get the same behaviour as `wc -L`, but ignoring the other ones which anyway we can't tell what influence they will have on the display width).

That covers TABs but not single-width or double-width characters. Note that the GNU implementation of `expand` currently  doesn't expand TABs properly if there are multi-byte characters (let alone zero-width or double-width ones).

```
$ printf 'ééééé\t\n' | wc -L
8
$ printf 'ééééé\t\n' | expand | wc -L
11
```

Also note that `./**/*.{c,h,p{l,y}}` would by default skip hidden files or files in hidden directories. As the brace expansion expands to several globs, you would also get errors (fatal with `zsh` or `bash -O failglob`) if either of those globs don't match.

With `zsh`, you'd use `./**/*.(c|h|p[ly])(D.)` which is **one** glob, and where `D` includes hidden files and `.` restricts to *regular* files.

For a solution that takes into account the actual width of characters (assuming all the text files are encoded in the locale's character encoding) you could use:

```
git grep -h '' ./**/*.(c|h|p[ly])(.) | tr '\r\f' '\n\n' |
  perl -Mopen=locale -MText::Tabs -MText::CharWidth=mbswidth -lne '
    $n++ if mbswidth(expand($_)) > 80;
    END{print 0+$n}'
```

Note that at least on GNU systems, `mbswidth()` considers control characters as having a width of `-1` and 1 for `expand()`. We assume no control character other than CR, NL, TAB, FF are found in the files.

Comment: “GNU wc -L doesn't treat TABs as 8 characters, it treats TABs as it would be displayed in a terminal with TAB stops every 8 columns.”  You’re correct, of course, but when tabs are used only for indenting that boils down to the same thing.

Comment: @phg, not if they're mixed with spaces (like 3 spaces, one tab, 3 spaces at the start of a line gives a width of 11 not 16).

Comment: For the purpose of this question we may assume the contributors were disciplined enough to indent consistently (or that they have git commit hooks in lieu of discipline).

Comment: @phg, looking at the Linux kernel source tree (an old checkout from May I had lying about), @roaima's approach finds 32408 too many lines. Not so much about mixed tab+spc indenting, but because tab is also used for column alignments for table-like sequences of `#define    symbol    value` or declarations.

Comment: Interesting result, but we’re not dealing with the the kernel tree here.

Comment: Interesting work. I'd bound _tab_ to beginning of line, which is where we were (latterly) advised it would only be found. I assume the 32000 or so "wrong" lines in your kernel source are those that place _tab_ elsewhere on the line?

Comment: @phg: No, it doesn't amount to the same thing when tabs are used for indenting, because tabs will expand to whatever your editor has set the tab stops to.  For instance, if I'm editing C, tabs are two spaces, if fortran, the first tab is to column 7, asm has still different tabbing...  And in Makefiles, where tabs have meaning, the tab char displays as a glyph rather than spacing.

Comment: @roaima, yes, like I said above, any time it's used for any sort of alignment. See for instance `curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915_reg.h | grep -c $'[^\t].*\t'`. That single file has over 6 thousand lines that contain TABs not used for indenting.

Comment: @jamesqf _tab_ is 8 characters. If you want to change that it's your issue. Almost all utilities that understand _tab_ as a tab action assume 8 character tab stops. Personally I use softtabs at 2 or 4 character indents; as indents build up to 8 my editor replaces them with a _tab_ (unless I'm writing python).

Comment: Sorry, that was 32000 too _few_, not _many_

Answer (score 1):

A solution with **ex** (from **vi**). Albeit slow.

As vi is able to correctly process UTF-8 data:

It could expand tabs to spaces, count control characters as 1, process `\r` `\t` `\f` `\v` correctly and also process most of **valid** UNICODE values. Including either composed (NKC) and decomposed (NKD) accents, and characters from Cyrillic, Arabic, Greek, Chinese, and many others.

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash --

declare -i count=0

for i do
    # Set ex script in one variable
    a='set expandtab        "       Expand tabs to spaces
       r '"$i"'             "       Read original file
       g/^.\{,80\}$/d       "       Remove all lines shorter than the value used
       wq                   "       Quit ' 

    o=outfile; :>"$o"           # Clean output file
    ex -s "$o" <<<"$a"          # process lines in $i file
    count+=$(wc -l <"$o")       # count and accumulate number of lines.
done

echo "$count"
```

Call script as:

```
$ script.sh     **/*.{c,h,p{l,y}}
44984
```